# New installation of Ruby Enterprise Edition - "gem" recognised but "sudo gem" isn't

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ruby-enterprise-edition

I've just installed Ruby Enterprise Edition on a fresh Ubuntu 10.04 server. I went to install my first gem, and hit a weird problem I never saw before.

Without sudoing, if I just type 'gem' I get the blurb about gem. I can switch to root and do `gem install gemname` or give the full path to the gem exe, but if I do `sudo gem install gemname` I get an odd error `sudo: gem: command not found`.

If I do `gem install gemname` without sudo, it tells me I don't have permission to alter the gem folder (which is fair enough).  It looks like something funny's happening when I sudo, basically.

I've added the Ruby bin path to my PATH variable in my .bashrc file, like so:

```
export PATH=/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.01/bin:$PATH
```

then reloaded .bashrc with `source`.   Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo -s` and then `gem install gemname`.

**Long Answer**
.bashrc file only affects the bash shell you are in, and sudo does not know about it because sudo does not directly look at your .bashrc. You can use `sudo -s` to get around this. You can also use `sudo -E` to try to preserve the environment while running sudo commands.

Using /etc/profile to change your PATH instead of .bashrc can also work as well.

Comment: thanks tin man.  I tried changing /etc/profile but that didn't help.  Do i need to reload it?  I tried exiting and ssh'ing on again but no dice.  Changing to root *does* work like i said but i still want to be able to straight sudo it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

Comment: Keating - this seems like the answer to a different question, i never said anything about sqlite.

Comment: I got an error when I install sqlite3-ruby with command: sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby. So I search the error, then found your title. When I finished it with command : gem install sqlite3-ruby. I just suggest you try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RVM, use `rvmsudo gem install gemname`.